# GOPATH issue in Jenkins build running on docker

Tags: docker, go, jenkins

I'm running Jenkins on docker container and also install golang in the container environment below is the docker file

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

USER root

# FROM golang    
ENV GOLANG_VERSION 1.13.5
ENV GOLANG_DOWNLOAD_URL https://golang.org/dl/go$GOLANG_VERSION.linux-amd64.tar.gz

RUN curl -fsSL "$GOLANG_DOWNLOAD_URL" -o golang.tar.gz \
    && tar -C /usr/local -xzf golang.tar.gz \
    && rm golang.tar.gz

ENV GOPATH /go
ENV PATH $GOPATH/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH

RUN mkdir -p "$GOPATH/src" "$GOPATH/bin" && chmod -R 777 "$GOPATH"

USER jenkins
```

after creating a docker image I run it into the container on port `8080`. When I hit URL `localhost:8080` then Jenkins UI opens and created the Jenkins job. I'm cloning my repo of git and in the build section of the job configuration is Execute shell commands are:

```
go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
dep init
dep ensure
cd test_case
go test -v *.go
```

I also run the command with `go get` to install all the dependencies then will show me the error in the build console.

For the above configuration, I'm facing the error:

```
+ go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
+ dep init
init failed: unable to detect the containing GOPATH: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/goapp is not within a known GOPATH/src
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can anybody help me out from this? If there is any mistake then please tell me cause I'm new to docker and Jenkins.

Comment: use ARG also  for that to work in build stage

Comment: I already set golang environment using ENV @LinPy

Comment: ENV will not work in build stage you need to use ARG

Comment: @LinPy you mean I need to change ENV with ARG right?

Comment: @LinPy can you please paste a sample of code what variables need to be change :(

Answer (score 0):

`+ dep init
init failed: unable to detect the containing GOPATH: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/goapp is not within a known GOPATH/src`

You can only run `dep init` from inside a directory in `$GOPATH/src/`

Your GOPATH env variable is set to directory `/go/`. But you are trying to run `dep init` in `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/goapp`.